# Getting Keyerror when parsing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

I have just made a program to parse some data from an api. The api gives data back with a JSON format. When I try to parse it it gives me a key error

```
    url = json.loads(r.text)["url"]
    KeyError: 'url'
```

This is the part of the code

```
url = json.loads(r.text)["url"]
```

I am trying to get the data in the plain field. Here is the output from the API:

```
{"updates":[{"id":"a6aa-8bd","description":"Bug fixes and enhancemets","version":"8.1.30","type":"firmware","url":"https://con-man.company.com/api/v1/file-732e844b","updated":"2017-07-25"}]}
```

Comment: You do understand that the only key in that object is "updates", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `url` since it is inside update (list), therefore you need to Pass index and then `key` :

One liner:

```
>>> url = json.loads(r.text)['updates'][0]['url']
'https://con-man.company.com/api/v1/file-732e844b'
```

Explicit

```
>>> jobj = json.loads(r.text)
>>> url = jobj['updates'][0]['url']
'https://con-man.company.com/api/v1/file-732e844b'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
url = json.loads(r.text)["updates"][0]["url"]
```

Comment: The `updates` key has values in list of dictionaries. You need to pass the index for `updates` and then access the `url` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "updates": [ 
              {
               "id":"a6aa-8bd",
               "description":"Bug fixes and enhancemets",
               "version":"8.1.30",
               "type":"firmware",
               "url":"https://con-man.company.com/api/v1/file-732e844b",
              "updated":"2017-07-25"
              }
           ]
}
```

Try to visualize of your dict, it has only one key "**update**" in that key value it has another **list** and into that list, you has another dict

so if in your case

```
 _dict = json.loads(r.text)   # read file and load dict
 _list = _dict['updates']     # read list inside dict
 _dict_1 = _list[0]       # read list first value and load dict 
 url = _dict_1['url']     # read 'url' key from dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and works now for me.

```
json_object = json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))['list'][0]['localPercentDynamicObjectsUsed']
```